# Integrating payments with Firebase for Android and iOS

Tags: firebase, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, payment-processing

I'm developing an app that will have to process payments that can potentially even be international. The first payment gateway that comes to mind is PayPal. Is there a simple guide about how to integrate PayPal with Android Studio or Xcode with Firebase as the backend?

Also, how do I integrate Adaptive Payments?

If you think, PayPal doesn't fit the bill, please feel free to suggest other payment gateways and the way in which I should integrate it.

PS: I have seen the SDK for PayPal but I'd like some first hand knowledge from somebody.

Answer (score 2):

You will find at the following URL an example (from Firebase) on how to implement Paypal payment with Cloud Functions (with the advantage that everything is done in the -serverless- backend):

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/paypal

Comment: Thanks, but I'm also looking at how to integrate card payments and the link that you shared seems to be specifically for PayPal accounts.

Comment: Thanks once again but Stripe is not supported in India.